# função update sql + php não funcionando corretamente

Tags: php, sql, funções

eu precisava fazer algo bem basico, eu to criando um site de clientes e preciso criar a função de diminuir em 1 a parcela do cliente na db, segue abaixo a função que eu montei

```
function quit() {     
  $sql ="UPDATE customers SET parcelas = parcelas - 1 WHERE id = ". $_SESSION['id'] .";";      
}
```

eu criei um formulário na pagina View e coloquei o action para redirecionar para um php separado com o método post, montei a função nessa pagina com a sessão já começada e chamei a função, porém nada acontece, eu sou redirecionado para a pagina principal sem sucesso. Já chamei um Var_dump e o problema não está na variavel, também confirmei se não estava usando varchar ao invés de int na table. Já tentei colocar manualmente o id e também o valor de parcelas, porém também não funcionou. Tentei inclusive colocar sem o Where para ver se a db era toda atualizada mas simplesmente não funciona, se alguém puder me ajudar eu ficaria agradecido.

update: eu conversei com um amigo e ele me lembrou do comando mysqli_query, o codigo entao ficou assim:

```
function quit() {     
  $sql ="UPDATE customers SET parcelas = parcelas - 1 WHERE id = ". $_SESSION['id'];   
$result = mysqli_query($sql);
}

quit();
```

porém ainda assim não tive nenhum resultado positivo

Comment: Primeiro coloca a quantidade de parcela em uma variavel depois atualiza

Comment: @BernardoLopes pra que fazer isso se o próprio comando update já faz isso?

Comment: já pegou o valor da variável `$sql` e tentou executar direto no banco? e o resto do código, não pode ser um problema nos comandos que executam esse update?

Comment: Se eu bem observei voce esta subtraindo 1 da coluna. "parcelas" é o nome da coluna, voce nao tem a quantidade de parcelas. Esta atualizando a coluna  "parcelas" com "parcelas" -1

Comment: eu testei manualmente o comando no phpmyadmin e funcionou corretamente, e sobre os comandos, eu chamei a função no mesmo arquivo php conforme tenho utilizado no projeto

Comment: Tenta assim ``$sql ="UPDATE customers SET parcelas = parcelas - 1 WHERE id = $_SESSION['id']"; ``

Comment: não vai funcionar pq nn ta fazendo concatenação com php, nn vai nem reconhecer o codigo